# Fullscreen flex layouts: Necessity of intermediate flex boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The following shows a test case for a typical flex layout with a fixed-sized header and a body that takes up the rest of the screen.

Elements in the body that are larger than the body scroll themselves, rather than making the whole page get a scrollbar.

There's is something that annoys me about this solution though: All intermediate divs (such as `#intermediate` in this sample) need to have `display: flex` as well. Just disable the css for `#intermediate` to see what I mean.

I can't find a way to stop non-flex divs to become larger than their parents when their combined children's height gets too tall.

That's annoying and confusing. Why is this necessary? Is there another way?

**EDIT:** Please note that this is a reduced sample - in my real case, the scrolling part is nested more deeply than just one level, which makes it more ugly to have to have all intermediate divs be flex boxes.

```css
html, body, #outer {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
}

#heading {
  background-color: red;
}

.row {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  background: beige;
}

#inner {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#intermediate {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="heading">
    Heading
  </div>
  <div id="intermediate">
      <div id="inner">
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not necessarily forced to use an intermediate div set with `display: flex;` if you just want this layout.
Check this example:

```css
html, body, #outer {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
}

#heading {
  background-color: red;
}

.row {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  background: beige;
}

#inner {
  align-self: flex-start;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="heading">
    Heading
  </div>
      <div id="inner">
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is no need for an intermediate: I simply use the `align-self` property to handle the position of the left bar (some good reference on flexboxes, if you didn't already read it: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

A good thing to notice is that this way, you cannot set some content on the right of the `#inner` div because the positioning if automatically done by the flexbox parent. If you want to do so, you'll end up using the `#intermediate` div.

> I can't find a way to stop non-flex divs to become larger than their
>   parents when their combined children's height gets too tall.

You cannot really because that's not the way it is rendered: inner div's are rendered first because they contain the content to display. Then, they are positioned in the parent which is itself rendered. If the parent has a constraint on the `height`, then the `overflow` property alter the rendering.

According to the doc (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow), the default `overflow` value is `visible` and the content won't be clipped. To prevent children divs to become larger than the parent, you have to set an `overflow`.

This answer has got quite big, don't hesitate to comment if it's not clear or if you need some extra info!

**EDIT**

As requested by OP, here is a sample without removing the `#intermediate` div and without having to set its `display` to `flex`:

```css
html, body, #outer {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
}

#heading {
  background-color: red;
}

.row {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  background: beige;
}

#inner {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#intermediate {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="heading">
    Heading
  </div>
  <div id="intermediate">
      <div id="inner">
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't *need* the intermediate divs, but all intermediate divs I have *need* to be flex boxes. I can't get rid of the intermediate divs for other reasons - my sample is a reduced demo, in the real world the scrolling content is more deeply nested.

Comment: Hmm that's odd. From my experience, i'd say you definitely not need to set `display:flex` everywhere, that's not the way it is supposed to work. Would you have a 'closer from the reality' sample to show?

Comment: Well, just get the existing sample to work without getting rid of `#intermediate` entirely and have it not be a flex box somehow.

Comment: As to your argument that inner div's are always rendered first: By using `height: 100%` or `position: absolute; bottom: 0; top: 0` you can make a div fill exactly the height of an ancestor in many circumstances, regardless of the size of child content. It's just when I introduced flex layouts that this no longer works.

Comment: Your edit is interesting. That seems to be it. Apparently the `#intermediate`'s direct child, `#inner`, gets *smaller* when you add `overflow: hidden`: Obviously there's no "hidden overflow" to be noticed, the child just scrolls more.

Comment: You can check my answer, as requested, i made it work without getting rid of `#intermediate` and without using flexboxes. I agree with you: using both this methods will fit your div exactly into its parent, but if its content is too tall, it will overflow, and this has nothing to do with flexboxes.

Comment: In particular, `#intermediate`'s height doesn't need to be `100%`, `98%` is no different. Bizarre.

Comment: @John It is not bizarre when you understand Flexbox. The percent can by any value that is higher than the `intermediate` minus the `header`, and when it becomes less, you'll see it will shrink

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find a way to stop non-flex divs to become larger than their
>   parents when their combined children's height gets too tall.
>
> That's annoying and confusing. Why is this necessary?

The `inner` need a height/max-height, or else the `overflow-y: scroll` won't have any effect.

So when you add `display: flex` to the `intermediate`, the `inner` becomes a flex row item, and as the `align-items` defaults to `stretch`, it pick up its parent's height and the `inner`'s content will scroll.

That can be proven by change `align-items: stretch` to i.e. `flex-start` as shown in this sample.

```css
html, body, #outer {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
}

#heading {
  background-color: red;
}

.row {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  background: beige;
}

#inner {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#intermediate {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="heading">
    Heading
  </div>
  <div id="intermediate">
      <div id="inner">
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

> Is there another way?

Yes, and beside `display: flex`, and with the given markup, the 2 most used is adding `height: 100%` on elements or using `position: absolute`, and I would go with `position: absolute`, as when using `height: 100%`, amongst others Safari had problem with picking up `height: 100%` from a flex item.

Also, when using `position: absolute`, any other child of `intermediate` can use `height` with a percent value and it will still work.

*Note, for absolute to work, the `intermediate` need to fill the remaining space left, which it won't do by default, so I added `flex-grow: 1` to it, ...and as you commented, when your tried `position: absolute; bottom: 0; top: 0`, you most likely forgot to do just that.*

```css
html, body, #outer {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
}

#heading {
  background-color: red;
}

.row {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  background: beige;
}

#inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  height: 100%; /*  width: 100%;  uncomment for full width  */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#intermediate {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="heading">
    Heading
  </div>
  <div id="intermediate">
      <div id="inner">
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

But to really make use of Flexbox, nested flex container's is the smartest solution, and partly was it was meant for, so we can stop using height and absolute positioning, and get a really good dynamic solution.

Finally I want to mention, there is yet another way to avoid `display: flex` on `intermediate`.

If the `intermediate` only holds the `inner`, a much more standard way to allow scroll would be to set the overflow on the `intermediate` instead of the `inner`

```css
html, body, #outer {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
}

#heading {
  background-color: red;
}

.row {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  background: beige;
}

#inner {
}

#intermediate {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="heading">
    Heading
  </div>
  <div id="intermediate">
      <div id="inner">
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, indeed I appear to have failed to test this properly and the `position: absolute; bottom: 0; top: 0` does actually work as well - that's reassuring. Thanks for the detailed response.